# Sort multidimensional np.array with given indices along an axis

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, keras

Let's say I have a np.array of shape (1,28,28,128), which is the output from a layer of ResNet50. I wanted to visualize the strongest 64 feature maps, how could sort the np.array?

Here is what I have done, but it gives me what I wanted, However, it does not sort the np.array.

```
feature_maps = np.random.rand(1,28,28,128)
idx = np.argsort(-1*np.sum(feature_maps,axis=(0,1,2)))
for i in range(64):
   plt.subplot(8, 8, i + 1)
   plt.imshow(normalize(feature_maps[:, :, idx[i]]), "gray")
   plt.axis("off")
```

Is there a simple way to sort np.array with known indices along an axis, like idx above?

Comment: Use `np.sort` to sort.  `np.argsort` gives you the indices that would sort the array.  Calling `np.argsort` on a temporary array, as you have done, doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse. I try to sort the ndarry according to the summation of elements on each of 128 planes, rather then simply sort them according to the value of element along an axis. np.argsort  does give a meaningful return, it gives an order indices, which can be used to retrive the planes from the ndarry in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.sort can't do the described job, the goal can still be achieved with slicing as below:

`feature_maps_sorted = feature_maps[:,:,:,idx]`